# Can use hammer.js pan events and still allow users to scroll?

Tags: javascript, hammer.js, touch-event

I have a UI where users are scrolling a horizontally scrolling area.

I still want them to be able to scroll left and right, but I'd like to fire an [Hammer.js pan event](http://hammerjs.github.io/api.html) at the same time. Here's my code at present:

```
var worksHammertime = new Hammer(scrollingArea);
worksHammertime.on('pan', function(ev) {
  if ( ev.direction === 2 ) {
    log('left', ev)
    Do things...
  } else {
    log('right', ev)
    Do things...
  }
});
```

Essentially I think I'm looking for the opposite of the `preventDefault()`behaviour that Hammer seems to use by default. Can use hammer.js pan events and still allow users to scroll?

Answer (score 5):

Apply a CSS property:

```
#touch-area
{
touch-action: pan-x pan-y !important;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work on Safari http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-touch-action

Answer (score 0):

This currently isn't supported, but you could try to do this with a nested element containing `style="overflow: auto;"`